# Neo4J Subquery over same property to calculate ratio

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working with a tweets graph. I'm trying to get the ratio between tweets in spanish and tweets in english.

When checking the number of tweets by language:

```
MATCH (twtEs:Tweet)<-[:HAS_WRITEN]-()-[:HAS_AS_PROFILE_LANGUAGE]->(l:Language)
RETURN DISTINCT l.languageCode, count(*)
\\ Result:
╒════════════════╤══════════╕
│"l.languageCode"│"count(*)"│
╞════════════════╪══════════╡
│"en"            │165392    │
├────────────────┼──────────┤
│"es"            │73693     │
└────────────────┴──────────┘
```

We can see the counts for each language.

But when trying to calculate the ratio directly:

```
MATCH (twtEs:Tweet)<-[:HAS_WRITEN]-()-[:HAS_AS_PROFILE_LANGUAGE]->(:Language{languageCode:'es'})
WITH count(twtEs) AS tweetsEs 
MATCH (twtEn:Tweet)<-[:HAS_WRITEN]-()-[:HAS_AS_PROFILE_LANGUAGE]->(:Language{languageCode:'en'})
WITH count(twtEn) as tweetsEn, tweetsEs
RETURN tweetsEs/tweetsEn as RatioTweetsEsvsEn;
\\ Result:
╒═══════════════════╕
│"RatioTweetsEsvsEn"│
╞═══════════════════╡
│0                  │
└───────────────────┘
```

Thats what I obtain, when it should be 0,44557.
I've been checking the documentation and other answers in Stackoverflow but haven't found something similar to use as example. Probably the second query is incorrect but I'm strugling to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

I'm running:

- Neo4j Browser version: 3.2.20
- Neo4j Server version: 3.5.8 (community)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because count values are Integers.

For example :

```
WITH 165392 AS v1, 73693 AS v2
RETURN v1/v2

╒═══════╕
│"v1/v2"│
╞═══════╡
│2      │
└───────┘
```

You can transform them to floats instead :

```
WITH 165392 AS v1, 73693 AS v2
RETURN v1*1.0f/v2*1.0f

╒══════════════════╕
│"v1*1.0f/v2*1.0f" │
╞══════════════════╡
│2.2443379968246644│
└──────────────────┘
```

Which would give for you :

```
MATCH (twtEs:Tweet)<-[:HAS_WRITEN]-()-[:HAS_AS_PROFILE_LANGUAGE]->(:Language{languageCode:'es'})
WITH count(twtEs) AS tweetsEs 
MATCH (twtEn:Tweet)<-[:HAS_WRITEN]-()-[:HAS_AS_PROFILE_LANGUAGE]->(:Language{languageCode:'en'})
WITH count(twtEn) as tweetsEn, tweetsEs
RETURN tweetsEs*1.0f/tweetsEn*1.0f as RatioTweetsEsvsEn;
```